# Mysql join to the same table where column only appears today

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I am searching for all occurences of `dT` (and some other info) from a table where the first occurrence of `dT` was today. Here is my sql so far.  Works... but slow (REALLY GLACIALLY slow on my 7.9M record table)...but works.  Ideas to make this better? I know it is solvable by a join instead of subquery but I am not sure how. `tS` is a unix epoch timestamp.

Sounds easy... but here is the structure:

```
id int(11) not null auto_increment
dT varchar(64)
lA double
lO double
tS int(11)
```

and here is the SQL:

```
select dT, round(lO,4), round(lO,4), tS from table_name where unix_timestamp(curdate()) <= tS and dT not in (select distinct(dT) from table_name where unix_timestamp(curdate()) > tS) order by tS desc
```

---

Addition: Someone asked for a index and explain... so here it is.

---

Okay, so dT is indexed as is tS.

```
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type           | possible_keys                                      | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                              |
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | table_name | range          | idx_table_name_ts                                  | idx_table_name_tS   | 5       | NULL | 86180 | Using where                        |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | table_name | index_subquery | idx_table_name_dT,idx_table_name_tS                | idx_table_name_dT   | 67      | func |   142 | Using where; Full scan on NULL key |
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: There isn't enough information provided. Do you have indices on `dT` and `tS`? [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17736491/edit) your question and add results of `DESC table_name` and `EXPLAIN of your query`.

Comment: Using not in is always slow.  Not exists is a better option.

Comment: Is `table_name` really supposed to be there twice, or are you just showing us an example that is using another `table_name` in your subquery? Please answer the question.

Comment: Someone else told me that for every result in the major query, the subquery is executed once.  That is why it is slow as well, i am assuming.  This is absolutely the wrong way to write it, i know...but it is -- at least -- functional.  I am looking for help to make it better. :)

Comment: table_name is a replacement for the actual name of the table.  I am searching one table for all records whose `dt` does NOT exist in that same table on earlier days.  Maybe with that description it will help.

Comment: Is `dT` `INSERT`ing a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())` always, when it is `INSERT`ing?

Comment: yes, dT is a current unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `NOT EXISTS` and without `DISTINCT` in subquery

```
SELECT dT, ROUND(lO, 4) lO1, ROUND(lO, 4) lO2, tS 
  FROM table_name d
 WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) <= tS 
   AND NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM table_name 
   WHERE dt = d.dt 
     AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) > tS
) 
 ORDER BY tS DESC
```

Comment: Thanks!  Great Job!  WAY FASTER